# How to fetch the file names present in the text file and delete that files using shell

Tags: shell

I want to delete some files mentioned in a text file .The  text would be in a single line like below along with some other data

```
Cannot Handle File:C:\patches\BUG2\abc.javaCannot Handle File:C:\patches\BUG2\xyz.javaErrors .
```

So now I want to fetch the file names like abc.java and xyz.java in the text file and delete them so How can we proceed with it using shell. Please help to resolve this

Comment: @anubhava yes there is no space after .java in the input file

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'unlink $1 while /File:(.*?)(?:Cannot|Errors)/g' input.txt
```

- `-l` adds a newline to prints
- `-n` processes the input line by line
- `(.*?)` matches "frugally", i.e. finds the shortest possible match
- `/g` matches globally, i.e. as many times as it can.
- [unlink](http://p3rl.org/unlink) removes a file.

So, the file name must be preceded by `File:` and followed by `Cannot` or `Errors`.

Comment: @vinod: Do you mean you have no Perl installed in your linux?

Comment: no and i need that logic to be added in my linux script

Comment: @vinod: What do you mean by "linux script"? Is it bash, sh, dash, csh, tcsh, ksh? What prevents you from copying the line I've shown here into the script?

Comment: @vinod: The line shown here is a legal sh script line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -o` and `xargs`:

```
grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]_$-]+\.java' file | xargs rm
```

Will get this output from `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]_$-]+\.java' file
abc.java
xyz.java
```

Comment: i am getting below error when i execute your command can you help                                                                                                Usage: grep [-c|A NUM|B NUM|C NUM] -[alqinsvxrdhLowuVEFG] [-U[[c][p][l|b|8|o|a]]]] [-bI] [-e pattern]
 [-f patternfile] [--basic-regexp] [--extended-regexp] [--fixed-strings]
 [--byte-offset] [--unix-byte-offsets] [--binary] [--text]
 [- NUM] [--context[=NUM]|--before-context=NUM|--after-context=NUM]
 [--word-regexp] [--revert-match] [--text] [--recursive] [--version]
 [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: What is your grep version and what is your OS?

Comment: So you're using windows `grep` but tagged your question as `linux`?

Comment: the grep version is Version 9.5 build 3505 which is present already

Comment: Instal gnu grep on Windows using this link: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm and my suggested command will work.